# How to change Softkeyboard layout on demand?

Tags: android, cordova

I am using PhoneGap on Android. I need to change the keyboard layout according to a specific need.
A good example would be to see how GMail app changes the keyboard layout when moving from one text item to the other. When you need to enter an email, you'll see the @ symbol showing but It will removed when the focus is on other text fields.

My UI is not native but rather html. I am using PhoneGap and showing the keyboard via JS API.
I'll probably have to add code to my Softkeyboard plugin I'm currently using.

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  In a native app what you can do is set different IMEOptions on each field describing them as different types of fields, and the keyboard will decide what layout is appropriate.  I'm not sure if you can do that via phonegap, but if you can that would be the method.

Comment: While I cannot set those IMEOptions on html inputs - I have full access to the native stuff via plugins. I'm looking for a pragmatically way to achieve the same. I hope this make sense.

Comment: Yes.  But I have a lot of knowledge of the keyboard APIs-  I was lead Android dev at Swype.  The ONLY thing that effects what keyboard layout to use is the imeOptions and the locale.  imeOptions are the programmatic way of doing things, there's no other api to suggest a layout, at least as of 4.1.  4.2 may have added one, but I doubt it.

Comment: Very well then. I'll have to think on some other way. Thank you very much!

Comment: There may be something in the javascript that allows you access to a subset of imeoptions-  I know we can tell web password fields from web normal fields and web email fields.  But that's the only thing you can really do.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<input type="email" />
<input type="tel" />
<input type="url" />
```